# While loop creating infinite loop although the condition is becoming false in java

Tags: java, while-loop

```
public class Sample {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    int array[]= {1,2,3};


    //it is used to display the array in format as 3,2,1,2,1,1

    public void sampleFunction(int size)
    {

        while(size >= 0)
        {
            System.out.println(array[size]);
            sampleFunction(size-1);
        }
        //end while loop

    }
    //end sample function

    // starting main class

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //creating object Sample

        Sample s = new Sample();

    //Calling sample function for display the array elements

        s.sampleFunction(2);
    }
    //end main class


}
//end sample class
```

Comment: Where do you see the condition becoming false?

Comment: change `while` to `if` to avoid infinite loop

Comment: What do you want to achieve may, what you are doing is wrong, tell us what about you want we might be able to help you...

Comment: i want the output as 3,2,1,2,1,1 for that i written a sample program you can find the code

Answer (score 3):

Java is [pass by value only](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40480/1065197). You're never updating the value of `size` inside the `while` loop, so `size` will always be greater than 0.

```
public void sampleFunction(int size) {
    while(size >= 0) {
        System.out.println(array[size]);
        sampleFunction(size-1);
        //this fixes your code...
        size--;
    }
}
```

---

Even better, since you're handling a recursive method, just remove the `while` inside it:

```
public void sampleFunction(int size) {
    if (size <= 0) return;
    System.out.println(array[size]);
    sampleFunction(size-1);
}
```

---

The problem using the `while` loop is that the value of `size` never changes. This is how the method is executed:

```
public void sampleFunction(int size) {
    //removed unnecessary code that doesn't generate problems
    while(size >= 0) {
        sampleFunction(size-1);
    }
}

public void main(String[] args) {
    sampleFunction(0); //it will be infinite like this...
}
```

Now, when you call `sampleFunction(0)`, this is what will happen:

1. `sampleFunction(0)` gets called.
2. The `while` loop will check if `size` (whose value is 0) is greater or equal than 0.
3. Since it is equal than 0, it will call `sampleFunction(-1)`.
   3.1. `sampleFunction(-1)` gets called.
   3.2. The `while` loop will check if `size` (whose value is -1) is greater or equal than 0.
   3.3. Since the condition is not met, do nothing.
   3.4. Finish `sampleFunction(-1)` execution.
4. Return to the `while` check. `size` value never changed. Go back to 2 (thus getting the infinite loop).

Hints when defining recursive methods:

- **Always** define the base case at the top of the method (if cannot be on top, define it as soon as possible you can in the method).
- After finishing the design, test it using paper and a pencil (or a pen) and try to follow its execution **there** (not by executing it in the pc). This will help you check if you missed something. Once you gain more experience, you can trust more in the design and run it (and hope it doesn't get infinite :P).

Comment: i am calling samplefunction(size-1) inside while loop  means it reducing the size even though it is calling the while loop again and again

Comment: @user3536558 calling the method by sending `size-1` doesn't change the value of the `size` variable in the method that called it with its previous value, thus the infinite `while` loop.

Comment: Surely you want to print out when `size == 0`?

Comment: i checked by printing the value of size . it is changed to -1 and become as infinite loop

Comment: may be because i want to print first element in the array

Comment: @user3536558 explained the problem at the bottom of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want recursion, why not simply:

```
public void sampleFunction(int size)
{
    if(size >= 0)
    {
        System.out.println(array[size]);
        sampleFunction(size-1);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks. i want to know why it not working with while loop . if condition is true then execute the block of statements else exit.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void sampleFunction(int size)
{

    while(size >= 0)
    {
    System.out.println(array[size]);
    sampleFunction(size-1);
    }
//end while loop

}
```

You mix up recursive calls with imperative loop, you should choose one :

```
public void sampleFunction(int size)
{

    while(size >= 0)
    {
    System.out.println(array[size]);
    size--;
    }
//end while loop

}
```

or

```
public void sampleFunction(int size)
{

    System.out.println(array[size]);
    sampleFunction(size-1);
    }
```

Comment: i want in recursive calling.i think your code will throw array index not found exception

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use `if` instead of `while` since for the looping part you are already using recursive algo.

```
        if(size >= 0)
        {
            System.out.println(array[size]);
            sampleFunction(size-1);
        }
```

This makes you approach to base condition in every sub recursive call, since in each recursive call size is getting decrementing and in last recursive step, size will be zero which will stop calling itself recursively and you'll get out of you method finally...

Comment: what do you mean not working with while loop, you simply have to use if condition, this makes you approach to base condition in every sub recursive call, since in each recursive call size is getting decrementing and in last recursive step size will be zero which will stop calling itself recursively and you'll get out of you method finally...

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void sampleFunction(int size){
        while(size >= 0)
        {
            sampleFunction(size-1);
        }   
    }
```

Think slowly and step by step...

1. size=1
2. while(1>=0)
3. size=0
4. while(0>=0)
5. size=-1
6. while(-1>=0)
7. evaluates false
8. then it goes right back to step 2 because you never finished your while loop in step 2.

The solution is to change the while to an if. Do you understand why it is looping forever now? You keep setting your size back to 0 in step 3. If you learn how to use your stepping tool in the debugger you would be able to visualize this.

Comment: @user3536558 can you visualize the steps? You should run the debugger and go step by step so you can visualize this process.

Comment: yeah. i checked it. can i know i using the while loop wrongly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Recursion, It would be like this for example:

```
public void sampleFunction(int size)
    {
       //Stop Condition
       if(size = 0)
        {
            System.out.println("END LOOP");
            System.out.println(array[size]);
        }
       else
        {
            System.out.println(array[size]);
            sampleFunction(size-1);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing to keep in mind with recursion is that it creates multiple copies of the parameters and local variables.  Suppose your `main` calls `sampleFunction(4)`.  Then `sampleFunction(4)` calls `sampleFunction(3)`, which calls `sampleFunction(2)`, which calls `sampleFunction(1)`, which calls `sampleFunction(0)`.  At that point, there are 5 versions of `sampleFunction` on the stack, that are all active at the same time; **and each one has its own** `size` **parameter**.  Also, if you had a local variable:

```
public void sampleFunction(int size) {
    int x = size * 100;
    ...
}
```

each of the 5 versions would also have its own `x` variable.  So the five methods that are now all active look something like this:

```
sampleFunction(4)   size=4  x=400   calls:
sampleFunction(3)   size=3  x=300   which calls:
sampleFunction(2)   size=2  x=200   which calls:
sampleFunction(1)   size=1  x=100   which calls:
sampleFunction(0)   size=0  x=0
```

There are now five `size`s, and five `x`s, in your program.  This should help you see why if, say, `sampleFunction(0)` changes `size` or `x`, that only affects its **own** `size` or `x`; it doesn't touch any of the others.  Also, when `sampleFunction(4)` calls `sampleFunction(3)`, the effect is that a **new** `size` variable (parameter) is created whose value is 3, but this does not affect `sampleFunction(4)`'s `size` at all--its value will be 4.  And if `sampleFunction(4)` doesn't do anything to assign to `size`, its own `size` will be 4 forever, which is why you're getting an infinite loop.

This applies to variables whose type is a primitive type, like `int`, and also to variables whose type is a reference to an object.  But note that it doesn't apply to objects themselves.  If you have a recursive method like:

```
public void recursiveMethod(MyClass c, int n) {
    ...
    recursiveMethod(c, n-1);
    ...
}
```

then if there are five `recursiveMethod`'s on the stack, there will be five different `c` parameters, but they will all refer to the same object, unless one of the `recursiveMethod` methods reassigns its **own** `c` to something else.